# How to add link to source code of the webpage?

Tags: css, html, web

What's the smoothest way to include source code of a page so that I don't have to rightclick the mouse and then select view page source ? I'd like it to be just a link which will open a new window presenting the code .

Comment: web grabber might help you..? not particular .. but try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for Firefox and Chrome, possibly other browsers as well

```
<a href="view-source:[page url]" target="_blank">View page source</a>
```